# how can i get the angular Velocity of an object? corona, lua

Tags: lua, get, coronasdk

I have a slowmotion mode and I need  to get the angular Velocity of an object so I can make it slower. I am using corona, lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular velocity should be around an origin. I write the algorithm below and also the formula in Lua below. But use this formula only for angles up to 6 degrees as bigger angles require more accurate formulas.

1- define Origin X0,Y0

2 - Object at time t1 is at x1,y1, get these values, from X0 and Y0

3 - Object at time t2 is at x2,y2, get these values, from X0 and Y0

Your angular velocity at t2 is

```
local Vang = math.atan  ( math.sqrt  ( (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2 )  /  math.sqrt (x1^2+y1^2) )
```

This will be the value in radians or its tangent. You can multiply by 180 and divide by 3.14 to get it in degrees.